# How to make a trunk in Asterisk 13 FreePBX to call to other SIP networks, a voip peering?

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, freepbx

**I have made a trunk to make calls within my sip group (i.e) sip.antisip.com
Now I want to make calls to another sip network (i.e) sip.fairytel.at.**

I know we need to make dedicate trunks for these, but I am not sure of the configurations that I should make.

For making calls with antisip I tried the context of the trunk as **default** or **from-pstn**. When I call from an extension to external antisip number, the call is connected but gets cut immediately. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here ? I have given the server name, port, username, secret and selected the codecs as ulaw and alaw. I have connected this to a outbound route with dialplans as 4XXXXXXX as the number which I am testing now is that. I gave a password to check if the outbound route works correctly and it works.

For making calls to fairytel, I am using a trunk with the same credentials but the context is **from-sip-external**. I have connected this to another new outbound route with a dialplan of 4NNNXNNNN1X which exactly matches my fairytel number. I am not sure, if I am going completely wrong somewhere or not ?

Comment: Debug questions are offtopic on SO. Can suggest you hire expert or go forum.asterisk.org

Comment: We need much more information to help. Is the call rejected on antisip.com or by asterisk? Any call flow/logs?

Comment: I think the rejection is by asterisk. But I set up two trunks, one to connect to antisip accounts and another one to connect to fairytel accounts. With two different outbound routes, I am able to call within these two voip providers with two accounts. But, is it possible to configure freePBX to make call from these accounts to any other sip account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes to make this work finally,

I setup **a trunk with antisip** credentials and **another trunk with fairytel** credentials The context in both cases were **from-pstn** and codecs were **ulaw and alaw** only. Later, I created tw**o outbound routes**.
One was called **antisip-outbound** and it has the **dial pattern of fairytel in it** (i.e) 479XXXXX and the **trunks were in the order antisip and then fairytel**. But, I think we don't need antisip here. Then. I created another outbound route call **fairytel-outbound** which has the **dial pattern of anti-sip** (i.e) 431XXXXXXX. The **trunks for this were fairytel first, then antisip**. 
Now, if I make a call from any extension, it knows if it should connect to the fairytel trunk or antisip trunk and makes the call correctly. This way, I got two different providers connected inside my freePBX.